# Iterate php for loop to include parent ID

Tags: php, loops, foreach, yii2

I have a table that store devices, and a table that store data captured during an audit. I'm writing this audit system using Yii2.

Here are snippets of my controller and view.

**Controller:**

```
public function actionAudit()
{
    $devices = Device::find()->all();
    $deviceAudits = [new DeviceAudit()];

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($devices); $i++) {
        $deviceAudits[] = new DeviceAudit;
        // Now, how to assign
        // foreach $deviceAudit->$device->id
        // (I am guessing an array_push here?)

    }
    ....
}
```

**View:**

```
...
<?php foreach ($deviceAudits as $index => $deviceAudit): ?>
<?= $form->field($deviceAudit, "[$index]device_id")->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($deviceAudit, "[$index]status_id")->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($deviceAudit, "[$index]notes")->textInput() ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
...
```

I have managed to retrieve the number of audits, but I am not sure how to include the foreign key "device id", for each inspection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easily fixed by modifying my controller to the following, here it is:

```
public function actionAudit()
{
    $devices = Device::find()->all();

    foreach ($devices as $device) {
        $deviceAudit = new DeviceAudit;
        $deviceAudit->device_id = $device->id;
        $deviceAudits[] = $deviceAudit;
    }

    ....
}
```